# Using silverlight controls in wp7 application bad?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile, toolkit

I have seen many examples online about using silver light controls in wp7 applications, but most people say that its bad practice because you should only be using controls only from the windows phone toolkit. I just want to know whats right?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer:* **No, it is not bad practice, as long as the controls were designed for Windows Phone**

*Long answer:* You should always make sure that you know the source of the controls. Although a lot of third-party controls are of solid quality, some  of them might be resource hogs if created by unexperienced developers. The controls bundled in the stock SDK are optimized by Microsoft devs, following the proper design and perf guidelines. There is no such guarantee with controls coming from external sources.